# Pass value to subject service Angular js

Tags: javascript, angular, subject

i try passa values to child component using subject service, I am based on [Documentatio](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-using-a-service), but somethink is wrong and when a try print data dont show nothing.

i have the navComponent which request api base on select input. When changing select update request and send new data to child page.

Service:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class SearchService {
    // Observable string sources
    private data = new Subject<any>();

    // Observable string streams
    value$ = this.data.asObservable();

    // Service message commands
    setValeu(value: any) {
        this.data.next(value);
    }


}
```

NavComponent:

```js
 async consultaIndicadores() {
    try {
      this.loading = true
      let con = await this.rq.postRequest(... request ...).toPromise()
      this.loading = false
      

      if (con.status == 200) {

          this.dados = con.data;
          this.search.setValeu(this.dados)

        }

      }
    } catch (error) {
      this.loading = false

      console.log(error)
    }
  }
```

childComponent

```js
  constructor(private trans: SearchService) {

    this.subscription = trans.value$.subscribe(val => {
      console.log(val);
    })


  }
```

in each component i seted provider, pass service to constructor etc... I dont know what its wrong. please help me

Comment: try subscribing in `ngOnInit()` lifecycle hook rather than the `constructor`.  When it comes to handle initial data, you should do it in `ngOnInit`

Comment: In your service you seem to be missing **.next()** on your promise. Without that you can't get the results.

Comment: @Charlie V, in "setValue" function.

Comment: I should have said **.then()**. In  statement ```let con = await this.rq.postRequest(... request ...).toPromise()`` you are getting a Promise. To get the results you need do this: ```con.then((value)=>{console.log(value});```